# Serverless cannot import local files;in same directory; into python file

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-plugins

I have a serverless code in python. I am using serverless-python-requirements:^4.3.0 to deploy this into AWS lambda. 
My code imports another python file in same directory as itself, which is throwing an error.

serverless.yml:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: functions/pleasework.handle_event
    memorySize: 128
    tags:
      Name: HelloWorld
      Environment: Ops
    package:
      include:
        - functions/pleasework
        - functions/__init__.py
        - functions/config

(venv) ➜  functions git:(master) ✗ ls
__init__.py             boto_client_provider.py config.py               handler.py              sns_publish.py
__pycache__             cloudtrail_handler.py   glue_handler.py         pleasework.py
```

As you can see, pleasework.py and config are in same folder, but when I do import config in pleasework I get an error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'functions/pleasework': No module named 'config'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

I am struggling with this for few days and think I am missing something basic.

```
import boto3
import config


def handle_event(event, context):
    print('lol: ')
```

Answer (score 2):

ok, so i found out my isssue. Way i was importing the file was wrong 
Instead of

```
import config
```

I should be doing

```
import functions.config
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pranay Sharma's answer worked for me.

An alternate way is creating and setting PYTHONPATH environment variable to the directory where your handler function and *config* exist.

**To set environment variables in the Lambda console**

1. Open the [Functions page](https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home#/functions) of the Lambda console.
2. Choose a function.
3. Under Environment variables, choose Edit.
4. Choose Add environment variable.
5. Enter a key and value.

In our case Key is "PYTHONPATH" and value is "functions"